# Formulario pide datos que no estan configurados en el diseño

Tags: ms-access

tengo una tabla llamada pacientes a  la cual le hice un formulario, pero la tabla tenia campos innecesarios elimine los campos de la tabla y ahora el formulario me  da error, (me pide los campos que borre), aunque en el diseño no estan, que podria ser y como puedo resolver el problema , lo que pasa es que no quiero repetirlo, porque tiene muchos datos y botones, Gracias por su ayuda..

Comment: Yo buscaría referencias a esos campos en expresiones; por ejemplo a lo mejor hay algún filtro o similar que los usa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Todos los formularios, en la vista Diseño, tienen una propiedad en la pestaña DATOS que se llama ORIGEN DEL REGISTRO. Ahí es donde debes seleccionar qué tabla o consulta es el origen de tus datos.

Si metiste controles (cajas de texto, cuadros de lista, etc.) asociados a campos que ya no están en la tabla o consulta de origen, en el formulario en la vista diseño saldrán con un aviso de que están "descolgados". El símbolo creo que era como una especie de pequeño triángulo verde con un signo de peligro. Otra opción simplemente es ir seleccionando de 1 en uno todos tus controles, y en la pestaña DATOS mirar a qué campo están vinculados, y si están vinculados a uno que ya no existe, borra ese control y solucionado.